# If $x,y$ are cadlag and for every $s$ either $x(s)=y(s)$ or $x(s)=y(s-)$ does $x=y$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that a certain function  is a metric on the collection of cadlag functions, that is functions that are continuous from the right and with left-hand limits, and in trying to prove that $d(x,y)=0 $ implies $x=y$ I'm able to show ath if $y $ is continuous at at point $s $ then $x(s)=y(s) $ and otherwise we have $x(s)=y(s-) $.  **Does this mean $x=y $?**

(In the above $y(s-)$ denotes the left-hand limit at s)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is cadlag? Ah, this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Càdlàg . First time I hear of this.